# KeyTouch remaps the delete key

Tags: keyboard

I installed KeyTouch, but it decided that the delete key should be the KeyTouch hot key.  So, when I pressed deleted, KeyTouch came up.  Next I uninstalled KeyTouch and now the delete key doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to remap the delete key to actually delete?

Notes:

- I tried reinstalling KeyTouch, and
  the same thing happens.
- KeyTouch does
  not allow the user to map the delete
  key.

**EDIT**

- xev shows keycode 119 when I press the delete key
- xmodmap shows keycode 119 mapped to `Delete NoSymbol Delete`
- running `xmodmap -e "keycode 119 = Delete"` from the command line does not resolve the issue

**EDIT**

- The delete key passes through correctly when using rdesktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out uninstalling KeyTouch and restarting fixed it.